# Cannot run ant from apache localhost (ant: command not found)

Tags: bash, apache, web, server, ant

I have setup my localhost on macOS big sur with apache and php (works fine). I now have a bash script that uses ant to build some source code, but I cannot run the ant command from within a bash script from the browser. I always receive `ant: command not found`. I can run the bash script from the terminal with my user and the webuser (_www) ant this works as intenden. But I cannot get it to work when I call the site from my browser. Any ideas?

Comment: *"from within a bash script from the browser"*.  How?  You did an exec from PHP?  Your Apache runs with a specific user, so when you call bash, it will create an instance of bash with the environment of that user, not yours.  So my guess, ant is in a directory that is not listed in the PATH variable of your apache user.  FYI please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, you were right the PATH variable was not set correctly.